# How to make separate REST controllers for nested resources? Spring Boot

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I have a REST controller. It processes the resource "messages". And each message can contain comments inside itself.

```
/api/v1/messages/1
/api/v1/messages/2

/api/v1/messages/1/comments/1
/api/v1/messages/1/comments/2
```

Here is a code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/messages/")
public class RestControllerV1 {

    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Message> getMessage(@PathVariable("id") Long messageId) {

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "{messageId}/comments/{commentId}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Comment> getComment(@PathVariable("messageId") Long messageId, @PathVariable("commentId") Long commentId) {

    }
}
```

It works fine. 
But I think that it is not very good to have one big controller for two resources. So I want different controllers (SOLID, S-principle).

```
MessageControllerV1
```

and

```
CommentControllerV1
```

Is it possible to divide controllers in Spring Boot application?

Answer (score 12):

You could have something like:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/messages")
public class MessageController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "{messageId}", 
                    method = RequestMethod.GET, 
                    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Message> getMessage(@PathVariable("messageId") Long messageId) {
        ...
    }
}
```

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/messages/{messageId}/comments")
public class CommentController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "{commentId}", 
                    method = RequestMethod.GET, 
                    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Comment> getComment(@PathVariable("messageId") Long messageId, 
                                              @PathVariable("commentId") Long commentId) {
        ...
    }
}
```